# Symfony throwing the following exception while clearing cache

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Currently, I am using symfony version 2.3

vendor/symfony/security-core/Exception/../../Resources/translations" directory does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we have your composer.json please ?

Try to change ur version of Symfony, go to the 2.2 version of Symfony.

I found this : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3519 who could help u to find ur bug.